# To prove change of variables

Tags: complex-analysis

[image: page1]

If G is an antiderivative of f,G exists since f is continous.
$G.(\phi.\gamma))'(t)= G'(\phi .\gamma(t)) . (\phi.\gamma)'(t)$.

How do I proceed after this?

Comment: You should use the definition of complex line integral.

Comment: Can  I get a more complete answer/proof @halbaroth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\gamma : [a, b] \to U$ be a path and $g: U \to \mathbb{C}$ continuous. The complex line integral of $g$ along $\gamma$ is defined as follow:
$$ \int_{\gamma} g(z) dz = \int_a^b g(\gamma(t)) \gamma'(t) dt. $$
Since $\phi$ is holomorphic, then $(\phi \circ \gamma)' = (\phi' \circ \gamma) \gamma'$.
Using the above definition twice, you get
\begin{align}
 \int_{\phi \circ \gamma} g(z) dz &= \int_a^b g((\phi \circ \gamma)(t)) (\phi \circ \gamma)'(t) dt = \int_a^b g((\phi \circ \gamma)(t)) \phi'(\gamma(t)) \gamma'(t) dt \\ &= \int_{\gamma} g(\phi(z)) \phi'(z) dz. 
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you @halbaroth!

Comment: how is the last statement accomplished? We have gone from ∫((ϕ∘γ)(t))ϕ′(γ(t))γ′(t)dt =  ∫g(ϕ(z))ϕ′(z)dz.

Comment: It is the definition of the complex line integral for the function $g \circ \phi$ along the curve $\gamma$.